# Fitting a gaussian function to set of points

Tags: c#, curve, data-fitting, gauss

In order to find the FWHM I need to find a Gaussian f corresponding to a set of (x,f(x)) values. The available fitting methods (I'm restricted to C#) assume the solution to be a polynomium of n'th degree (or that's what I've been able to find so far). I'm wondering if there exists a specialized fitting method/scheme aimed at finding Gaussians. Or is there a generalized method out there that converges fast? 
   I can provide a good guess for the middle of the bell curve and its height but no more than that.

Comment: See the fowlloing post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950733/gaussian-curve-fitting-algorithm. It simply estimates the average and standard deviation to obtain the gaussian fit.

Comment: Thanks for your link. This is for finding the Gaussian g for a function f, so that g describes the properties of f. I have sample points for the Gaussian, not the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by observing that

ln(y) = ln(a) - ½(x-b)^2/c^2

which gives

c = sqrt(½(x-b)^2/ln(a-y))

So with a and b known it was a no-brainer :)